# Proving Mobius formula for cyclotomic polynomials without using $x^{n} - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, mobius-inversion

I know that using the equation

$$x^{n} - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)$$

we can prove

$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{d\mid n} (x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}$$

by taking logs and using Mobius inversion. What if I don't want to use the first equation? Are there other methods to prove the second equation??

Comment: What do you want to show exactly, from where do you start ? And why would you want to avoid $\mu(n)$, whereas its definition is very simple : $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) = 1_{n=1}$ ? $\qquad$ [And for example see there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991513/show-that-if-operatornamechark-0-then-f-dx-prod-cdxd-c-1-m/1993913#1993913) the kind of answer you can except for the construction of $\Phi_n(x)$

Answer (score 1):

For instance, the inclusion-exclusion principle. $\Phi_n(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of a primitive $n$-th root of unity: we may label any $n$-th root of unity according to the degree of its minimal polynomial and recall that the roots of $x^d-1$ are the $d$-th roots of unity (primitive or not). By the inclusion-exclusion principle,
$$ \prod_{d\mid n}(x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)} $$
is the product of the terms $(x-\xi)$ where $\xi$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, i.e. $\Phi_n(x)$.